# How is the Ubuntu server image for Raspberry Pi built?

Tags: server, raspberrypi, disk-image

I am trying to figure out how the Ubuntu server images for Raspberry Pi are created. The ones you can download from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

In my search I have found a few tools, such as ubuntu-image and the classic branch of pi-gadget at https://github.com/snapcore/pi-gadget/tree/classic

However, I can't connect the dots between these two.

All information I can find is related to the Ubuntu core or snap version, which is not what I am looking for, I'm trying to figure out (and eventually modify) the classic image.

Update: I've been experimenting a bit more and it looks like a missing link is `snapcraft prime`. It transforms the pi-gadget repo into something ubuntu-image can use. However, it does not seem to work crossplatform. I'm trying to build on amd64 and get `Makefile:18: *** Build architecture is not supported.  Stop.` When I try the same on a Raspberry Pi, the issue is that core20 image is not supported by multipass. Apparently it is possible to use another build environment, so I'm looking into that now.

Update2: Based on @guiverc's response, the actual build system might be still something completely different.

Update3: I've sort of given up on figuring this out. I don't know where the actual scripts are located, but, from context, I believe the system works as follows:

1. The base image is created using the `pi-gadget` in combination with `snapcraft` and `ubuntu-image`. From what I gather, this results in a kernel, device tree and an (empty?) root file system. AFAIK Raspberry Pi does not require a bootloader in the image, but for other "gadgets", this step would also generate a bootloader.
2. Next, the actual root filesystem is populated using the seeds and germinate.

In spite of multiple efforts, I am unable to successfully run the `snapcraft prime` operation. I was able to configure it to run on a Raspberry Pi (using LXD instead of Multipass, which came with its own issues). So I'm a stuck.

Even after that, I wouldn't know how to use `germinate` to build the file system. All information I can find seems outdated. I can only guess that `germinate` somehow generates a list of packages and files that need to be copied into the filesystem. But I doubt that it will actually go out and download and build those required files, there's probably another tool for that.

I'm currently looking into `ELBE` and `CustomPiOS`. These use an existing image and repackage it with the desired content. Not exactly my preferred method, but at least it looks like these tools will actually work. I will also look into the Ubuntu MATE YT explainer video.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu ISOs are built by [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) from seeds stored there.

eg. in [https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/) you'll find the seeds for *jammy* or Ubuntu 22.04, which include a [desktop-raspi](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/desktop-raspi) seed that tells launchpad what to include in the build of desktop, and [server-raspi](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/server-raspi) for server.

This applies to [*flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu as well.

Comment: How doe the seeds fit into the build process? They are apparently processed by germinate, but the only documentation I can find is pretty old. For instance, I can't find the germinate output for raspi in here: https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/germinate-output/

Comment: Note:  I'm not a *developer*, but am involved with a *flavor* of Ubuntu.  If we have an issue with why something is on an ISO (*I'd usually explore the manifest for this*), we'd then look at why on the *seeds*.  If we needed to re-spin an ISO (here I'm thinking of *daily* images, currently that's *jammy* or *kinetic*) a *Product Manager* would login to a web site and cause a new ISO to be spun (by launchpad). I'm not involved with any r.pi images as the *flavor* I'm doesn't have one, but logging into the site shows the same options for Rasp.Pi images for Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Server

Comment: Do note - People who aren't Product Manager won't see the options to *rebuild* etc. that I'm referring to here in the *Administration* section at bottom of page  (*for most users there is no Administration section shown*)   I can't provide the technical detail you're looking for sorry (*I'm not a developer as stated before*) and my experience is mostly in QA where something occurs on a *daily* and thus I'm providing details of where I'd look, and if actually required (after fix), how I could cause a new *daily* to be generated.

Comment: No problem, I have one more pointer to try to figure this out!

Comment: Minor correction (*not that it matters*):  I mentioned *jammy* & *kinetic*, and should have included *focal* too  (*20.04.5 hasn't been released yet!*)

Comment: My answer doesn't mention it, but once all *daily/final* (or really *RC* or *release candidate*) images for a release are marked as ready, the *Ubuntu Release Team* cause them to be copied to a released image at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ when & only when they decide the release is ready to go. The *Ubuntu Release Team* follow their documented procedures, that end up creating the ISO & images we generally all download & use.

Comment: I'll add another link; but not an Ubuntu official image (ie. **not** created on lp), but Ubuntu-MATE *lead* just posted a video on the creation of Ubuntu MATE 22.04 for the raspberry pi - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPX8R1FpHG4    This was created by a Ubuntu *flavor* team not on Ubuntu infrastructure & maybe closer to what you want; not what you asked for as I read it & maybe worth a look (*Ubuntu MATE is a desktop image, not server*) & include details on the **build script** used for Ubuntu-MATE.